# ExtJS: Is there a way to handle memory management

Tags: javascript, memory-management, extjs

We are building a rather large extjs application, with tons of windows and components etc. Is there any 'best practices' or functions to keep memory under control?

When looking at the Chrome resource usage, everytime I open a window the memory usage goes up (which makes sense) but doesnt go back down when closed. If I reopen the same window it once again goes up

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Closing the window probably just hides it.

Try deleting the variable using javascript [delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/delete)

Comment: Ih ave been using destroy to remove all its containing items, does that work in the same way?

Comment: In the source you cited: "delete is only effective on an object's properties. It has no effect on variable or function names."  Does this actually work on variables despite that assertion?